# On reload with default browser button go to original HTML

Tags: java, html, css

I have 2 html documents, first is like pre-load animation with button that goes to original site(2nd html). After i press reload page it only reloads and stays on second html document instead of going to beginning.

Can please someone explain this.

Comment: What does this have to do with Java?  Did you mean to tag it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

As for what understand from what you are doing, you can't just retrieve to previous page just by refreshing.

When you refresh in your browser, it'll reload the `location.href`.

If you can use javascript, you can try doing something like this

```
location.href = document.referrer
```

And you can create an anchor tag, or a link, on the second page to go back to the last page with a button similar to this (havent't tested it)

```
<a href="#" onclick="location.href = document.referrer; return false;">Back</a>
```